# Dynamic route inside a static tree

Tags: php, apache

I have a directory structure of static files that I'd like to serve with my web server. Say:

```
project/
    directory1/
    directory2/
    directory3/
        subdirectory1/
        subdirectory2/
        subdirectory3/
            static.html
            static.png
            static.js
            static.css
...
```

Nothing magic until there, here is a simple vhost we could use.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project.dev
    DocumentRoot "path/to/project"
    <Directory "path/to/project">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now lets say we want to intercept `GET http://project.dev/directory3/subdirectory3/static.html` do some script and serve what we want instead.

**Question**: How would we configure our Apache vhost to use php, python, ruby or whatever language to interpret this request and return some response instead of the actual static file ?

Something like:

```
#...
<Directory "path/to/project">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "path/to/project/directory3/subdirectory3/static.html">
    send_to_some_framework "path/to/project/app.php"
</Directory>
#...
```

Comment: you don't want `<directory>` that applies to DIRECTORIES (obviously), not individual files. try `<Location>` or `<Files>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Something like :

```
RewriteRule ^/directory3/subdirectory3/static.html$ path/to/project/app.php [L]
```

or with [`AliasMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch):

```
AliasMatch "^/(.*/static\.html)$" "path/to/project/app.php$1"
```

Comment: `AliasMatch` actually worked for me. (Alternative added in answer to intercept `*/static.html`)